# How can I make Google Chrome use flat theme icons for open close expand buttons?

Tags: 16.04, unity, google-chrome, icons, themes

I just recently installed flatabulous theme on Ubuntu. Everything looks great! That is, except Google Chrome. I'm trying to get the close minimize and expand buttons to look like the theme I'm using. Can someone help me out?

[image]

Comment: In Settings > Appearance, try "Use System title bar and borders" maybe?

Answer (score 0):

To make Google Chrome use the system them, Follow these steps.

1. Open Chrome And click on the hamburger icon (settings)
2. Go to Appearance.
3. Select the "Use GTK+ theme" option
4. Relaunch Chrome

That's it.

If you want the buttons to work on window mode too, right click on the top bar of the Chrome window and select the option "use system title bar and borders".